# Wrapping an RSA private key with AES key and then unwrapping

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, webcrypto-api

I've been trying to password protect an RSA private key generated with Web Cryptography API. To do this,

1. I first generate an RSA key pair
2. Then I derive an AES symmetric key from a password
3. Then I wrap the RSA private key from step1 with the AES key from step2.
4. When I'm done, I try to verify this worked by immediately passing all of these to `unwrap` method where I try to unwrap it

---

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<script>
function wrap(password) {
  var iterations = 1000000;

  // Utility function
  var stringToByteArray = function(s){
    if ("TextEncoder" in window) {
      encoder = new window.TextEncoder;
      return encoder.encode(s);
    }
    var result = new Uint8Array(s.length);
    for (var i=0; i<s.length; i++){
        result[i] = s.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return result;
  }

  var saltBytes = stringToByteArray("NaCl");
  var passphraseBytes = stringToByteArray(password);

  return crypto.subtle.generateKey({
    name: "RSA-OAEP",
    modulusLength: 2048,
    publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]),
    hash: {name: "SHA-256"}
  }, true, ["encrypt", "decrypt"]).then(function(keyPair) {
    return crypto.subtle.importKey(
      "raw", passphraseBytes, {name: "PBKDF2"}, false, ["deriveKey"]
    ).then(function(baseKey) {
      return window.crypto.subtle.deriveKey(
        {name: "PBKDF2", salt: saltBytes, iterations: iterations, hash: "SHA-1"},
        baseKey,
        {name: "AES-CBC", length: 256},
        false,
        ["encrypt", "decrypt", "wrapKey", "unwrapKey"]
      ).then(function(wrapperKey) {
        var iv = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16));
        return crypto.subtle.wrapKey(
          "pkcs8",
          keyPair.privateKey,
          wrapperKey,
          {name: "AES-CBC", iv: iv }
        ).then(function(wrappedKey) {
          return {
            iv: iv,
            wrapper: wrapperKey,
            wrapped: wrappedKey
          }
        })
      });
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  })
}


function unwrap(account) {
  console.log(account);
  crypto.subtle.unwrapKey(
    "pkcs8",
    account.wrapped,
    account.wrapper,
    {
      name: "AES-CBC",
      iv: account.iv
    },
    {
      name: "RSA-OAEP",
      modulusLength: 2048,
      publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]),
      hash: {name: "SHA-256"}
    },
    true,
    ['decrypt', 'encrypt']
  ).then(function(privateKey) {
    console.log("unwrapped = ", privateKey);
  }).catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e)
  })
}

// Finally I call "wrap" and then "unwrap"
wrap("password").then(unwrap)

</script>
</html>
```

But the code doesn't work. The wrapping code doesn't throw any error and seems to generate the keys (although I have no idea if these are valid or not). But when I try to run the `unwrapKey` method, I get the following error:

```
DOMException: Cannot create a key using the specified key usages.
```

I've been pulling my hair out for the last 24 hours because I can't get this to work. Can anyone spot a problem? This is a perfectly self-contained piece of code so you can try it out by copy and pasting into an HTML file and opening in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do, wrapping the public/private key with a symmetric key, is not how wrap/unwrap is intended to work.

> - `wrapKey`, allowing the key to wrap a **symmetric** key for usage
>     (transfer, storage) in unsecure environments.
> - `unwrapKey`, allowing
>     the key to unwrap a **symmetric** key for usage (transfer, storage) in
>     unsecure environments.

You can wrap/unwrap a symmetric key but you cannot wrap/unwrap a public/private key pair (or key) since the wrap/unwrap probably expects the wrapped key to be a symmetric key and not an asymmetric key.

> The `SubtleCrypto.wrapKey()` method returns a Promise of a wrapped
>   **symmetric** key for usage (transfer, storage) in unsecure environments.
>   The wrapped buffer returned is in the format given in parameters, and
>   contained the key wrapped by the give wrapping key with the given
>   algorithm.
>
> The `SubtleCrypto.unwrapKey()` method returns a Promise of a CryptoKey
>   corresponding to the wrapped key given in parameter.

Comment: If you're speaking based on Mozilla documentation, I don't trust them when it comes to WebCrypto API because I learned that their documentation is incomplete and sometimes misleading at least for WebCrypto API. The original W3C proposal doesn't have any such restriction and the spec says it's just an encryption mechanism. Also, since I asked this question, I've found a library that does this https://github.com/safebash/OpenCrypto

Comment: Indeed that is the Mozilla documentation and indeed that is the status of most (all?) current major browsers. Also the W3C doesn't restrict the wrapping, as you say. However... The above is what is available through the broswer API for developers. Good that you found a solution that implements your requirements. In all: Bad implementation by the MBC... (Major Browser Consortium)... Happy New Year!